# Eclipse Run Configuration - Multiple Run configurations in single configuration?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

i have a situation where my Project **MAIN** contains **SubProject A** and **SubProject B** and when ever i make changes in SubProject A and SubProject B.

i have to do maven clean and maven install for SubProject A and SubProject B
and then MAIN Project Update.

Is there any way to achieve all this in single configuration ?

Something like :

Configuration MainProject does:
clean ,build A, clean,build B, clean,build MainProject.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to achieve all this in single configuration ?

Of course you can. This is a skeleton for a maven multi module project:

parent POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myProject</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <modules>
        <module>moduleA</module>
        <module>moduleB</module>
    </modules>
    <build>
          ....
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
           ....
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
           ....
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Be aware of `<packaging>pom</packaging>`.**

This is the POM for moduleA:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
        <groupId>my.group</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>moduleA<artifactId>
    <name>moduleA</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>       <!-- this is default  -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
          <!-- no version here, see dependencyManagemant in parent POM -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <!-- no version here, see dependencyManagemant in parent POM -->                <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Analog for moduleB, but with dependency to moduleA.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>nbaWorker</artifactId>
        <groupId>de.lgn.aaabk</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>moduleB</artifactId>
    <name>moduleB</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>       <!-- this is default  -->

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>my.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>moduleA</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
          <!-- no version here, see dependencyManagemant in parent POM -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <!-- no version here, see dependencyManagemant in parent POM -->                <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Now, you can call `mvn clean install` **on the parent** whenever you make changes on a module.

Here are more informations:
[Tutorial How do I ...](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-create-a-multi-module-project-in-eclipse.html)

[From Sonatype](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html)

[From maven Homepage](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html). At this time, not so helpful, and there is a broken link.

Comment: What if i want to include moduleA in multiple Parent poms ? how can i declare <parent> in that case ?

Comment: @Roxy hmmm ... I'm not sure if this is possible with pure maven. Also I would say that using a module in more than one multi module project violates the concept. If a module has a universal meaning in different projects, it is a dependency in these projects.

Comment: You are right. it is dependency,probably i have not cleared my self . and when i make some changes in these dependencies then i need to build these dependencies first and then main project, so i wanted to overcome this problem of building first dependencies somehow.

Comment: @Roxy perhaps in eclipse you can make a build configuration which always calls `mvn clean install` on your moduleA before you build the multi module project.

Also, it may helpful to know that you can use the conecpt of parent POM not only in multi module projects, but also in standalone artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

To do that I declare a profile in my top level parent POM like this

```
    <profile>
        <id>build-all</id>                              
        <modules>
            <module>MAIN</module>       
            <module>SubProjectA</module>        
            <module>SubProjectB</module>                                    
        </modules>
    </profile>
```

At the eclipse Run Configuration use the parent POM path as base directory and "build-all" as profile.

Remember that you must declare the parent POM as parent of the other POMS.

Comment: Thanks, could you please give me some reference, where i can read about Super pom and why do we need it. Googling alone is not so helpful

Comment: I sould have said "parent POM" instead of super POM